# Отличие UWP от WinForms при обращении к элементам

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

В WinForms при создании элемента мы могли просто кликнуть на него - и студия создавала обработчик события для этого элемента, например

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Достаточно было просто вписать

```
Button1.Text = "Поменяли текст кнопки"
```

И всё бы заработало. Но в UWP приложении при нажатии на ту же кнопку студия создает тот же обработчик, но называет его уже

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

И обратится теперь к элементу интерфейса никак нельзя. Разве что в самом Xaml-e написать имя(по умолчанию его нет) и обращаться уже по нему

```
<Button Content="Button" **Name="btn1"** HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="123" Width="264" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

И еще у самой кнопки нет аттрибута текста. Есть даже

```
btn1.FontSize
```

А текста нет. 
Вообщем, объясните пожалуйста для переходящих с WinForms - зачем эти вещи убрали, и что поставили им на замену?

Comment: Вместо Text там Content. Потому что внутри кнопки может быть не только текст, а что угодно, хоть таблица с веббраузером и встроенное видео.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Парадигма совсем другая - это развитие идей `WPF`. Нужно учить паттерн `MVVM` - без него все грустно. Все что касается отображения - пишется в xaml, та же кнопка это по сути контейнер куда ты можешь напихать еще элементов - да, даже кнопку внутрь кнопки можно хоть до посинения напихать, для того же текста внутрь надо поместить `TextBlock`:

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock>Нажми меня</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

из кода можно пихать в свойство `Content` - но так делать не надо, поскольку `View` полностью задается через декларативную xaml разметку. В принципе по старенькому тоже можно, но как вы заметили - нужно принудительно давать элементам имена и от изучения `xaml` разметки все равно никуда не деться - и будет это путь тернистым и в целом бессмысленным. Такова цена офигенной визуальной гибкости `WPF` относительно `WindowsForm`. В парадигме `MVVM` имена элементов нужны крайне редко - код с отображением относительно слабо связаны через привязки и команды. В частности это позволяет с легкостью разным людям работать над UI и бизнеслогикой не особо при этом пересекаясь. Ну и легкость тестирования тоже огромный плюс.